# How to add product video to custom carousel / gallery on product page

Tags: magento2, product, template, gallery, video

The below code is how my product page gallery/carousel is pulling in images, how can I include product videos in this?

```
<div class="pdp-gallery__carousel">
    <?php foreach($images as $image): ?>
        <div class="pdp-gallery__image">
            <img src="<?php echo $image->getData('medium_image_url') ?>" class="main-image">
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The video URL can be accessed inside the `foreach` with `<?php echo $image->getVideoUrl();?>`.

As we only want to add the video URL when required we can check the `mediaType` in an if statement - `<?php if ($image->getMediaType() === 'external-video'): ?>`.

My full carousel including the video (I haven't updated classes yet, don't judge ;)):

```
<div class="pdp-gallery__carousel">
    <?php foreach($images as $image): ?>
        <div class="pdp-gallery__image">
            <?php if ($image->getMediaType() === 'external-video'): ?>
                <img src="<?php echo $image->getData('medium_image_url') ?>" href="<?php echo $image->getVideoUrl();?>" data-fancybox="pdp-images" class="main-image">
            <?php else: ?>
                <img src="<?php echo $image->getData('medium_image_url') ?>" class="main-image">
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```